# Calling Multiple Jquery function using OnclientClick

Tags: javascript

Is it good practice to call multiple Jquery functions using OnClientClick=" TempDelete();Delete();"? I resulted to this option because I wanted the TempDelete() to finish executing before Delete(). When I used both functions within one call like this: if(x > 0)
{

`TempDelete();`
`Delete();`
} There wasn't a consistency in execution, sometimes the Delete(); was executed before the TemDelete(); It's more of an advice rather than anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should add event listeners in javascript, not in the markup

```
$(function(){ // or $(document).ready()
    $('#callOnClick').on('click', function(){
        TempDelete();
        Delete();
    });
});
```

You should also look into the `$.when()` and `$.then()` methods, and the `$.Deferred()` object.

for instance

```
$.when(TempDelete).then(Delete);
```

You should also follow the javascript convention for functions: first capital letter for constructors

```
function Person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

and first lower letter for methods or functions:

```
function getStuff(obj){
    return obj.property;
}

var obj = {
    hello : function(stuff){
        alert(stuff);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks my Issue relates to making an Ajax Asynchronous call Synchronous and your response pointed me to the right direction. This link helped http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118772/execute-one-ajax-request-after-another-ajax-request-finished

Answer (score 0):

This should be no problem, because inside the handler code is called synchronously.

I code a little example. The counter is always incremented before the div is added by the second method "Delete()".

HTML:

```
<div id="callOnClick">Push me</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
var counter = 0;
function TempDelete() {
    counter++;
}

function Delete() {
    $('#callOnClick').after('<div class="Delete">Delete: '+counter+'</div>');
}

$("#callOnClick").click( function (e) {
    TempDelete();
    Delete();
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
    cursor: pointer;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    background: gray;  
}

.Delete {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    color:white;
    background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/61hzv0v2/1/

Maybe you have two event listeners in your code?

Hope it helps.